# My Hard Disk Drive is very slow

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, bsod

This HDD is probably the worst. Windows 8.1 constantly gives me this error DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE accompanied by the BSOD. After playing games, the BSOD would happen. I looked up on the internet about this error and it says the HDD received invalid amount of power, that's why it crashed.

Anyways, when playing Watch Dogs, the gameplay was seriously laggy up to the point when I just want to smash my PC. I could tell that my GPU is capable of the graphics, but not the hard disk, the hard disk activity indicator was lit (instead of flashing), which to me it means it's reading the map constantly.

UPDATE: the below are the replies to Holiness David's questions.

1. The hard drive is somewhere 30% to 40% full.
2. I have 4GB of RAM.
3. This laptop was just bought recently.
4. As mentioned above, this laptop was bought recently so the HDD shouldn't be very fragmented.
5. I was certain my AV wasn't scanning the HDD.

Comment: What is the question?  If you suspect the HDD I would replace it.  I suggest you verify which drivers were loaded when you receive the BSOD before you replace the hdd though

Comment: upload the dmp files from C:\Windows\Minidump to a cloud service and post a link. Also post pictures of this tool: http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html so that we can see if you have isues with the HDD

Comment: If your hard drive is receiving invalid amounts of power, then your HDD drivers are at fault... try updating them

Comment: @AntoOswin i dont know how to update HDD, and i believe there are no HDD driver softwares...

Comment: http://driverwhiz.com/device-drivers/hard-drive-drivers/hdd-drivers you might try this... but my suggestion would be that since your laptop is new, I guess it might still be under warranty. You better send it to the service center as they might have the EXACT and correct drivers suited for your system configuration and the HDD itself.

Comment: again please post the picture of the tool and share the dmp files. Otherwise I can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

How full is the hard drive? If the hard drive is somewhat full, the little HDD light will stay on a lot.  So, a lot of data is going to the HDD.

How much memory do you have? It is possible that too much data is going to Swap File just like when the HDD is almost full or badly fragmented.

How long ago was Windows 8 installed? Was it a fresh install or did you install it over another Windows OS like Vista or windows 7?

Have you ever done a defragment (defrag)?

Do you have an antivirus program scanning the HDD? That will tie up the HDD.

Comment: I have posted my answers to your questions. Please see my uodated question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on your laptop a lot, you need to defrag everyday or at least once per week.  Check out Mydefrag. Also, you should consider going with 8GB memory.  What size or capacity is you HDD and what is the RPM (should be 7200RPM. How hot is the computer getting (put your hand on the bottom)?  Does the HDD give problems when cold or just after its been running for a while?
Is this laptop still under warrantee?
What is the minimum hardware requirements as stated by the game?
I looked up the failure driver_power_state_failure, go to this URL to rea up on it (its a good website): http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001152.htm
It is possible that there is nothing wrong wih the HDD.
Seriously consider Mydefrag and more memory.
Ah...BSOD...do check to see how hot the bottom is getting.
Keep me posted; I'mhappy to help.